# Problem with latex files

Tags: filesystem-access

I have a problem with one of my latex files. I was writing when my laptop stopped working. I don't know why, but I had to force it to restart and when I turned it on I had problem with my latex file: I try to open it, but when I do Texmaker (also texstudio and texworks) don't work properly and don't open it. I tried to open it from onedrive, but all I see is a series of questions mark (like it is encrypted or something). Instead, all my other latex files have no prolem.

Can someone help me to understand what happened?

Comment: Texmaker seems to have such issues when something goes wrong and the computer is restarted. It's not the first time I see questions like yours. Recover the file from a backup.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). If it is being backed up in the cloud there is probably a back up of an earlier version. This si one of the reasons I recommend people work in a dropbox folder as it keeps a backup of every version. Has saved me numerous times.